# Xubuntu - Right Click Does not work

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, mousepad

I installed Xubuntu (Ubuntu 14.10) and everything works perfectly except the right click does not work... it acts as a left click. No matter what I do, I can't figure out how to enable right clicking. I'm using a laptop, not an external mouse...

Also, when I put the computer to sleep, the mouse completely stops working. The touchscreen on my laptop still works (so I can power it down that way), but this is really annoying as well.

I've got a Dell Inspiron 15 series.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have similar problem in the future, the right click on touchpad for Xfce is **three fingers tap** (not two fingers tap, it is used as middle click). It works on my Dell Vostro 5480. I found this combination accidentally while I was trying other Display Manager.

Comment: In my Xubuntu 18.04 two-finger-click (or tap) does work as right-click, but I do not know what the gesture for middle-click is.